# RichTextBox RTF to LaTeX

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, latex, rtf

I am having a RichTextBox that allows user to enter a string that may have bold characters. The string is then stored in XML and transformed to LaTeX using XSLT. I am having issues with the RTF parsing. Making any characters except the first character bold, works fine as the RTF bold tag is inserted properly as shown below.

[image]

However, if the first character is bold, the opening RTF bold tag will be placed somewhere in between the RTF prefixes as shown below. Therefore, conversion of bold characters from RTF to LaTeX may have issues if the first character is bold.

[image]

Any solutions to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What is meaning of `f0\fs18`?

Comment: You'd have to show the RTF source, together with all your C# and XSLT code. Otherwise, your problem is impossible to diagnose.